# Why on my render the object tries to run a query statement right before returning back to the view?

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I'm getting a weird problem on my controller.
I have this code:

```
orgUnit = OrgUnit.findById(orgUnitId)
            log.info("Org Unit 11: " + orgUnit)
            log.info("Org Unit 12: " + orgUnit.status.description)
            log.info("Org Unit 13: " + orgUnit?.orgUnitParent?.shortCode)
            log.info("Org Unit 14: " + orgUnit?.orgUnitParent?.name)
```

It works fine and show everything I need. Right after that I have this code:

```
render (['success': true, 'orgUnit': orgUnit, 'status': "--", 'parentOrgUnit': " - "] as JSON)
```

And I get this error:

```
ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

I'm not on the service, so there shouldn't be a proxy on my object. And I don't use anything that is not being used on the log.info, so the information is already there...

Can someone give me a direction on how to solve this one?

I'm using Grails on this project.

THank you!

Comment: Can you `log.info("JSON: ${(orgUnit as JSON)}")` successfully?  Can you turn on hibernate SQL logging and see what query it's running? (I'm not sure if orgUnit is being rendered as JSON in your response or just the `toString()`)

Comment: Depending on your version of Grails, the `log.info` statements may not be being executed. Are you seeing the output in a log somewhere?